# Java-Like 'throws'-information in method signature C#

Tags: c#, .net, programming-practices, exceptions, exception-handling

From Java I know that the signatures of methods that can throw exceptions contain a `throws` block, that contains the Exception(s) that might be thrown.
In C# there is no such thing and it is also not common practice to include such info in the XML-Header.
Is there a generally accepted way of drawing attention to potential exceptions or a place to commonly denote them?

Comment: See this stackoverflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4088114/c-sharp-explicitly-defining-what-exceptions-are-thrown

Comment: @KilianFoth thanks. However that mostly just confirms what I already knew. My question is, how people in the industry in fact do it. That other people have the same questions supports me in the idea that there has to be a way, other than "It ain't in the specs, so why should I care".

Comment: @Mark - people in the industry think that checked exceptions are a mistake to not be repeated. There are a few outliers that use contracts to enforce something similar, though they are decidedly uncommon.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

XML headers (e.g. [`<exception>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/vstudio/w1htk11d(v=vs.100).aspx)) are the best way of drawing attention to exceptions in C#, as this information will appear in IDE when typing the function name, as well as in auto-generated docs.  However you cannot force a user to deal with the exception since C# specifically avoids checked exceptions.

Most people don't put exception information in XML doc comments because it's too much work with low payoff, but if it was to be done, this would most reliably draw attention to the exceptions thrown.

Comment: Especially if you combine it with the various documentation generation tools out there.